# Controller searching for view instead of returning a different view method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have two controller actions outlined below:

```
public ViewResult TitleStorylines(int id)
    {
        var vm = Service.Get(id);
        vm.IsEditable = User.HasPermission(SecurityPermissionType.ManageStorylines);
        return View(vm);
    }

public ViewResult TitleStorylinesCreate(TitleStorylineModel model)
    {
        var created = Service.Create(model);
        return TitleStorylines(created.TitleId);
    }
```

I only have one view in my project, called `TitleStorylines`, which the first controller action handles fine. But when I call the second method, it gives me an error saying that it can't find the view called `TitleStorylinesCreate` even though I'm explicitly calling the previous method. What gives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try ?

```
return View("TitleStorylines",created.TitleId);
```

**EDIT: Based on your update** : I guess you are posting your form back the TitleStorylinesCreate. So probably after saving, dont you want to redirect the user back to the Get action of same ?

```
[HttpPost]
public ViewResult TitleStorylinesCreate(TitleStorylineModel model)
{
    var created = Service.Create(model);
    return RedirectToAction("TitleStorylines",new { @id=created.TitleId});
}
```

In the above example we are doing the [PRG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern. **Post -> Redirect -> Get**
After saving, we are redirecting them back to the first method. It will be a `HTTP GET` method.

Comment: Well, I should have specified that my first method takes in the titleid and gets information from the database and then jams that into a view model and then returns the view.

Answer (score 0):

```
        public ActionResult TitleStorylinesCreate(TitleStorylineModel model)
{
    var created = Service.Create(model);
    return RedirectToAction("TitleStorylines",new { @id=created.TitleId});
}
```